# Retrieving web page through servlet in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How do I retrieve a webpage by a Servlet passed as a form parameter from a JSP page?

The JSP page has a form with textbox to enter the url as a string and a submit button. The action is performed by a servlet which fetches the webpage from the url passed and displays the retrieved webpage.

Here i have my servlet code `

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
    * Servlet implementation class Search
    */
    @WebServlet("/Search")
    public class Search extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
     public Search() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

/**
 * @param  
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String html = null;

    String server = request.getParameter("browsebox");
    if(server != null && server !="")
        {

            response.sendRedirect("browse.jsp");

        }

        try {
            html = getWebPageFromUrl(server);

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            return;

        }
        response.setHeader("serchbox", server);
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if(html == null) {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>Refresher</title></head>");
            out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">");
            out.println("<p>The servlet has received a POST. This is the reply.    </p>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
        } else {



            out.print(html);
        }
    }








/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request,response);
}


private String getWebPageFromUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {

    // Create a URL object from urlString
    URL stockURL;

    try {
        stockURL = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            String msg = "Invalid url: " + urlString;
            throw new Exception(msg);
            }

    // Open a connection to the URL
    URLConnection stockConnection;

    try {
        stockConnection = stockURL.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            String msg = "Can't open connection to " + urlString;
            throw new Exception(msg);
            }

    // Get the InputStream from the URL connection
    InputStream webPageInputStream;

    try {
        webPageInputStream = stockConnection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // Could be any server error, but the most likely is 404
            String msg = "404 File Not Found: " + urlString;
            //throw new WebPageGrabberException(msg);
            throw new Exception(e.toString());
            }

    // Read the web page via the InputStream

    StringBuffer webPageData = new StringBuffer(32000);
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    boolean moreToRead = true;
    byte[] readBuf = new byte[4096]; // Read the web page in 4K chunks

    while (moreToRead) {

        int numBytesRead = 0;

        try {
            numBytesRead = webPageInputStream.read(readBuf);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                moreToRead = false;
                numBytesRead = -1;
                }

        if (numBytesRead > 0) {

            totalBytesRead += numBytesRead;
            webPageData.append(new String(readBuf, 0, numBytesRead));
            } else {
                moreToRead = false;
                }

        }

    try {
        webPageInputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        // Ignore any exception that might occur
            }

    webPageData.setLength(totalBytesRead);
     webPageData.toString();
}
}
```

I am getting blank from the servlet, when the form is submitted.

Comment: It all starts with code. Where in writing the code did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Dicey! You are going to end up with someone entering ../../../../etc/passwd (or similar) and are you going to display it? Give us some code so we can see what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to display the site in its entirety, just redirect to it.

```java
response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("url"));
```

If you need to display the site embedded in your JSP page, use an iframe.

```xml
<iframe src="${fn:escapeXml(param.url)}"></iframe>
```

*(the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `fn:escapeXml()` is just there to prevent possible XSS attacks)*

Either case, you may only want to validate beforehand if the URL starts with http:// or https:// and so on.